# Enable GPS in a device owner app

Tags: java, android, gps, device-owner

According [API documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setSecureSetting(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) a device owner app can modify a few "secure settings" and specially the [LOCATION_MODE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#LOCATION_MODE) with the following call :

```
devicePolicyManager.setSecureSetting (ComponentName admin, 
            String setting, 
            String value)
```

> Called by profile or device owners to update Settings.Secure settings
>   [...]
>
> A device owner can additionally update the following settings:
>   LOCATION_MODE

According my understanding the value of LOCATION_MODE is an int (resp. 0 for location disabled, 1 for GPS only, 2 for battery saving mode and 3 for high accuracy).

My problem is the type of the `String value` parameter. LOCATION_MODE requires an int, but the API requires a String.

Did I miss something ?

Comment: LOCATION_MODE documentation => ...bla...bla...  *putInt(ContentResolver, String, int)* click ... *Convenience function for updating a single settings value as an integer* ... *Note that internally setting values are always stored as strings* ... *this function **converts***  ... ***to a string***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is simply to use the String representation of the int value.

For instance to enable "gps only" location mode :

```
DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
if (dpm.isDeviceOwnerApp(context.getPackageName())) {
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, MyDeviceAdmin.class);
    dpm.setSecureSetting(componentName, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE, String.valueOf(Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_SENSORS_ONLY));
}
```

---

[Thanks to @Selvin comment]

It make sense, because when digging into javadoc for [LOCATION_MODE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#putInt(android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String,%20int)), you can read :

> Note that internally setting values are always stored as strings[...]