# How can I turn on mobile data and location service programmatically without the user having to do anything?

Tags: android

I am creating an anti-theft app that will turn on mobile data and GPS service when the phone is lost. However, the best I have been able to achieve so far is the following...

[image]

But if the phone is lost, the user has no way of pressing the "Yes" button. Is there any way or workaround to enable location and mobile data programmatically?

The user can give the necessary permissions the first time he/she runs the app. But after that the app will automatically turn on mobile data and GPS on its own when it receives an sms from a trusted contact. Is there any way I can achieve that?

Comment: When the user opens the app. It will click on YES and if it clicks NO then show warnings. But once it is done then app can control the internet but GPS it needs permission.

Comment: You can if your app is a device administrator. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286821/enable-gps-in-a-device-owner-app